# Differences between prior distribution and prior predictive distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, inference, data-mining, hierarchical-bayesian

While studying Bayesian statistics, somehow I am facing a problem to understand the differences between prior distribution and prior predictive distribution. Prior distribution is sort of fine to understand but I have found it vague to understand the use of prior predictive distribution and why it is different from prior distribution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Predictive here means predictive for observations. The prior distribution is a distribution for the parameters whereas the prior predictive distribution is a distribution for the observations.

If $X$ denotes the observations and we use the model (or likelihood) $p(x  \mid \theta)$ for $\theta \in \Theta$ then a prior distribution is a distribution for $\theta$, for example $p_\beta(\theta)$ where $\beta$ is a set of hyperparameters. Note that there's no conditioning on $\beta$, and therefore the hyperparameters are considered fixed, which is not the case in hierarchical models but this not the point here.

The *prior predictive* distribution is the distribution of $X$ "averaged" over all possible values of $\theta$:

\begin{align*}
p_\beta(x) &= \int_\Theta p(x , \theta) d\theta \\
&= \int_\Theta p(x \mid \theta) p_\beta(\theta) d\theta
\end{align*}

This distribution is *prior* as it does not rely on any observation.

We can also define in the same way the *posterior predictive distribution*, that is if we have a sample $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$, the posterior predictive distribution is:

\begin{align*}
p_\beta(x \mid X) &= \int_\Theta p(x ,\theta \mid X) d\theta \\
&= \int_\Theta p(x \mid \theta,X) p_\beta(\theta \mid X)d\theta \\
&= \int_\Theta p(x \mid \theta) p_\beta(\theta \mid X)d\theta.
\end{align*}
The last line is based on the assumption that the upcoming observation is independent of $X$ given $\theta$.

Thus the posterior predictive distribution is constructed the same way as the prior predictive distribution but while in the latter we weight with $p_\beta(\theta)$ in the former we weight with $p_\beta(\theta \mid X)$ that is with our "updated" knowledge about $\theta$.

**Example : Beta-Binomial**

Suppose our model is $X \mid \theta \sim {\rm Bin}(n,\theta)$ i.e $P(X = x \mid \theta) = \theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}$.
Here $\Theta = [0,1]$.

We also assume a beta prior distribution for $\theta$,  $\beta(a,b)$, where $(a,b)$ is the set of hyper parameters.

The *prior predictive distribution*, $p_{a,b}(x)$, is the [beta-binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) distribution with parameters $(n,a,b)$.

This discrete distribution gives the probability of getting $k$ successes out of $n$ trials given the hyper-parameters $(a,b)$ on the probability of success.

Now suppose we observe $n_1$ draws $(x_1, \dots, x_{n_1})$ with $m$ successes.

Since the binomial and beta distributions are [conjugate distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) we have:
\begin{align*}
p(\theta \mid X=m)
&\propto  \theta^m (1 - \theta)^{n_1-m} \times \theta^{a-1}(1-\theta)^{b-1}\\
&\propto  \theta^{a+m-1}(1-\theta)^{n_1+b-m-1} \\
&\propto \beta(a+m,n_1+b-m)
\end{align*}

Thus $\theta \mid X$ follows a beta distribution with parameters $(a+m,n_1+b-m)$.

Then, $p_{a,b}(x \mid X = m)$ is also a beta-binomial distribution but this time with parameters $(n_2,a+m,b+n_1-m)$ rather than $(n_2,a,b)$.

Upon a $\beta(a,b)$ prior distribution and a ${\rm Bin}(n,\theta)$ likelihood, if we observe $m$ successes out of $n_1$ trials, the posterior predictive distribution is a beta-binomial with parameters $(n_2,a+x,b+n_1-x)$. Note that  $n_2$ and $n_1$ play different roles here, since the posterior predictive distribution is about:

> Given my current knowledge on $\theta$  after observing $m$ successes out of $n_1$ trials, i.e $\beta(n_1,a+x,n+b-x)$, what probability do I have of observing $k$ successes out of $n_2$ additional trials?

I hope this is useful and clear.

Comment: Yeap, I believe I have understood what you have explained here. Thank you very much.

Comment: good answer, but your integral expressions don't look right, and clearly have unstated assumptions about the prior/likelihood built in. The general integral is $p(x|X)=\int p(x,\theta|X)d\theta$ (ie integrate joint distribution to get marginal)

Comment: @probabilityislogic Thank you for pointing this out. I edited my answer, I hope this is better now.

Answer (score 14):

Let $Y$ be a random variable representing the (maybe future) data. We have a (parametric) model for $Y$ with $Y \sim f(y \mid \theta), \theta \in \Theta$, $\Theta$ the parameter space. Then we have a prior distribution represented by $\pi(\theta)$. Given an observation of $Y$, the posterior distribution of $\theta$ is 
$$
   f(\theta \mid y) =\frac{f(y\mid\theta) \pi(\theta)}{\int_\Theta f(y\mid\theta) \pi(\theta)\; d\theta} $$
The *prior predictive* distribution of $Y$ is then the (modeled) distribution of $Y$ *marginalized over the prior*, that is, integrated over $\pi(\theta)$:
$$
f(y) = \int_\Theta f(y\mid\theta) \pi(\theta)\; d\theta
$$ that is, the denominator in Bayes theorem above. This is also called the *preposterior distribution* of $Y$. This tells you what data (that is $Y$) you expect to see before learning more about $\theta$. This have many uses, for instance in design of experiments, for an example, see [Experimental Design on Testing Proportions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235750/experimental-design-on-testing-proportions/270076#270076) or [Intersections of chemistry and statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366139/intersections-of-chemistry-and-statistics/366145#366145).

Another use is as a way to understand the prior distribution better. Say you are interested in modeling the variation in weight of elephants, and your prior distribution leads to a prior predictive with substantial probability over 20 tons. Then you might want to rethink, typical weight of largest elephants is seldom above 6 tons, so a substantial probability over 20 tons seem wrong. One interesting paper in this direction is [Gelman](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/prior_context_2.pdf) (which do not use the terminology ...)

Finally, preposterior concepts are typically not useful with uninformative priors, they require prior modeling taken serious. One example is the following: Let $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta, 1)$ with a flat prior $\pi(\theta)=1$. Then the prior predictive of $Y$ is 
$$ 
f(y)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 (y-\theta)^2}\; d\theta = 1
$$
so is itself uniform, so not very useful.