# Bayesian statistics -- interpreting the mean and standard deviation of priors

Tags: bayesian, prior

I have just started reading about Bayesian statistics and have a question regarding the general interpretations of priors. Let’s say I have recorded the reaction times (RT, in ms) every time a single subject pressed the space bar as fast as possible, without paying attention to any stimuli.  I would like to know how long it takes to press a key for this subject.

Before analyzing my data, I am making three assumptions: (1) There is a true (unknown) underlying time $\mu$ that the subject needs to press the space bar, but (2) I allow there to be some noise $\sigma$, but (3) such noise is normally distributed (though positively skewed because of the hard lower bound of 0 associated to time).

In a Bayesian linear model, we need to define (i) the likelihood as $RT\sim Normal(\mu, \sigma$), similarly to a frequentist model; and, additionally (ii) the priors for the two parameters in (i) -- i.e., $\mu$ and $\sigma$. Defining priors is highly subjective, but let’s say that we expect the following:

$$\mu \sim Normal(400,10)$$
$$\sigma \sim Normal_{+}(100,10)$$

I read this in the following way:

1. for the parameter $\mu$, our prior is that RTs have a mean of 400ms and a stdev of 100ms. If I am not wrong, this means that 68% of the data are expected to be between 390ms and 410 ms (and the overall distribution to range, approximately, between 370ms and 430 ms).
2. for the parameter $\sigma$, our prior is that the average standard deviation of the data will be 100ms, with a standard deviation of 10ms. I understand this as meaning that, on average, the standard deviation of the data will be 100 ms away from the mean of the data (with a standard deviation of 10).

But if the above is true, I am in fact expecting 68% of the data to range from approximately 300 ms to 500 ms  (since I am assuming a mean of 400, as for the prior of the mean) ±10 ms (since this is the standard deviation of sigma). If this is true, then I am not expecting the distribution of my RTs to be between 370ms and 430 ms (as it was based on the prior for mu). I am in fact expecting it to approximately be between 100 ms and 700 ms.

Is this the right interpretation of this? Also, if this whole reasoning is correct, then why not directly specifying this information (i.e. that we are in fact expecting RTs to range from 100 to 700 ms) in the prior for $\mu$?

Comment: Your interpretation of (the distribution of) $\mu$ and $\sigma$ is correct. The next thing you were asking for is the distribution of $RT$ generated from a normal with $m$ and $\sigma$ drawn from their respective priors. This is called a [prior predictive distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/394672). It's confusing to people new to Bayesian statistics, because the spread of the data partly also comes from the uncertainty (i.e., distribution) of the parameters that characterize the likelihood.

Comment: "then why not directly specifying this information (i.e. that we are in fact expecting RTs to range from 100 to 700 ms) in the prior for " the art/science of mapping from intuitive statement about the variables of interests to formal prior distributions is called *elicitation*